# virtualbox changes get lost

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

How do I copy `virtualbox` machine to another host (with somewhat different hardware configuration, at least with different CPU) without losing changes made? Both hosts are running `Windows 7/64 bit version`.

When I copy the corresponding `*.vdi, *.vbox files and logs`, then add the machine on the another host and run it (it is `Ubuntu`) I find that there are no changes available. It seems like the initial state of the OS.

I haven't find the `snapshot` folder (I searched for it in `C:\users\&lt;myusername&gt;\VirtualBox`). Neither I've found the snapshots.

How do I copy the virtual machine so that changes persist? Should I take a snapshot manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of VirtualBox are you running? There is an option called "Export Appliance" under the File option, which will create a ova/ovf file. I use ova extension, which will create a single .ova file. Once it is created, copy the ova file to the destination and select "Import Appliance" from File menu. That's it. It should work fine.
I have moved a VM from Ubuntu to Windows XP, it worked fine. BTW, I am running VirtualBox 4.3.8.